# gtk draw "expose-event" and redraw

Tags: gtk, redraw

I want to use `expose-event` to draw something then update or redraw. That's to say, there are a drawing area and a button in window. When clicking button, the drawing area will be redrawn accordingly. My problems are

1. In the following code, if I changed `gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (box), canvas);` to `gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), canvas, FALSE, FALSE, 0);`, nothing is drawn. Usually we use `gtk_box_pack_start` to add something into box. Why doesn't it work this time?
2. The function `build_ACC_axis` refreshed(deleted what has drawn) drawing area and prepared for new draw. But it didn't delete what has drawn. Why? How to refresh the drawing area?

If the source file is test.c, then compilation is

> gcc -o test test.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`

The code is below:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <glib.h>

static void draw (GdkDrawable *d, GdkGC *gc)
{
  /* Draw with GDK */
  gdk_draw_line (d, gc, 0, 0, 50, 50);
  gdk_draw_line (d, gc, 50, 50, 50, 150);
  gdk_draw_line (d, gc, 50, 150, 0, 200);

  gdk_draw_line (d, gc, 200, 0, 150, 50);
  gdk_draw_line (d, gc, 150, 50, 150, 150);
  gdk_draw_line (d, gc, 150, 150, 200, 200);

  gdk_draw_line (d, gc, 50, 50, 150, 50);
  gdk_draw_line (d, gc, 50, 150, 150, 150);
}

static gboolean expose_cb (GtkWidget *canvas, GdkEventExpose *event, gpointer user_data)
{
  GdkGC *gc;

  gc = gdk_gc_new (canvas->window);
  draw (canvas->window, gc);
  g_object_unref (gc);

  return FALSE;
}

void build_ACC_axis (GtkWidget *button, GtkWidget *widget)
{
  GdkRegion *region;

  GtkWidget *canvas = g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(widget), "plat_GA_canvas");

  region = gdk_drawable_get_visible_region(canvas->window);
  gdk_window_invalidate_region(canvas->window, region, TRUE);
  gtk_widget_queue_draw(canvas);
  /* gdk_window_process_updates(canvas->window, TRUE); */
  gdk_region_destroy (region);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *canvas, *box, *button;

  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request(window, 500, 300);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  box = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE, 0);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), box);

  canvas = gtk_drawing_area_new ();
  g_object_set_data(G_OBJECT(window), "plat_GA_canvas", canvas);
  /* gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), canvas, FALSE, FALSE, 0); */
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (box), canvas);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (canvas), "expose-event", G_CALLBACK (expose_cb), NULL);

  button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("ok");
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), button, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
  /* gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (box), button); */
  gtk_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT(button), "clicked", GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(build_ACC_axis), window);

  gtk_widget_show_all (window);

  gtk_main ();
}
```

I would like to answer my second question. After clicking button, it would send `expose-event` signal and run `expose_cb`. Since there is no change in `draw` function, we can't see the refreshing. Following is the updated code that can show refreshing. The point is to add variable `factor`. But for the first question, I still didn't know why.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <glib.h>

int factor;
static void draw (GdkDrawable *d, GdkGC *gc, double fac)
{
  /* Draw with GDK */
  gdk_draw_line (d, gc, 0, 0, 50, 50 * fac);
  gdk_draw_line (d, gc, 50, 50, 50, 150);
  gdk_draw_line (d, gc, 50, 150, 0, 200);

  gdk_draw_line (d, gc, 200, 0, 150, 50);
  gdk_draw_line (d, gc, 150, 50, 150, 150);
  gdk_draw_line (d, gc, 150, 150, 200, 200);

  gdk_draw_line (d, gc, 50, 50, 150, 50);
  gdk_draw_line (d, gc, 50, 150, 150, 150);
}

static gboolean expose_cb (GtkWidget *canvas, GdkEventExpose *event, gpointer user_data)
{
  GdkGC *gc;

  gc = gdk_gc_new (canvas->window);
  draw (canvas->window, gc, factor);
  g_object_unref (gc);

  return FALSE;
}

void build_ACC_axis (GtkWidget *button, GtkWidget *widget)
{
  GdkRegion *region;

  GtkWidget *canvas = g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(widget), "plat_GA_canvas");

  region = gdk_drawable_get_visible_region(canvas->window);
  gdk_window_invalidate_region(canvas->window, region, TRUE);
  /* gtk_widget_queue_draw(canvas); */
  gdk_window_process_updates(canvas->window, TRUE);
  gdk_region_destroy (region);
  factor++;

}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *canvas, *box, *button;

  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

  factor = 1;
  window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request(window, 500, 300);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  box = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE, 0);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), box);

  canvas = gtk_drawing_area_new ();
  g_object_set_data(G_OBJECT(window), "plat_GA_canvas", canvas);
  /* gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), canvas, FALSE, FALSE, 0); */
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (box), canvas);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (canvas), "expose-event", G_CALLBACK (expose_cb), NULL);

  button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("ok");
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), button, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
  /* gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (box), button); */
  gtk_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT(button), "clicked", GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(build_ACC_axis), window);

  gtk_widget_show_all (window);

  gtk_main ();
}
```

Comment: You need to set some initial size for the drawing area, try adding `gtk_widget_set_size_request(canvas, 200, 200);` after you create the drawing area widget. To clear contents of `GdkWindow` you can make use of `gdk_window_clear` but seem have figured out what was happening anyway